# driver.quit() doesn't work in Cucumber with multiple StepDefinition files - Selenium - Java

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, testng, bdd

I am creating a CUCUMBER-Testng-Selenium framework to run parallel BDD tests.
The @After doesn't seem to be working when there are multiple StepDefinition Files.
I get this error

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.quit()" because "driver" is null
```

I understand that the driver instance is not getting passed to the @After method that sits in StepDefinition1 file.

Is anyone having the same combination of framework having multiple StepDefinition files, if so, how do you quit each instance of the browser using @After?

```
    @After
    public void after() {
        driver.quit();
    }
```

The above common method is in StepDefinition1 and the tests involving StepDefinition2 are failing

Answer (score 0):

you should have driver as a public variable in the base class and also make it is thread safe . You have to make even the reports thread safe

```
public static ThreadLocal<WebDriver> driver = new ThreadLocal<WebDriver>();
driver.set(driver)
```

Now change **driver** as **driver.get()** everywhere example

```
driver.findElement changes to driver.get().findElement()

driver.get changes to driver.get().get()
```

Else the specs running in parallel will try to access the same object and when the first thread closes the driver using driver.quit() the remaining threads try to access the closed driver and you will get errors.

**Also when running parallel tests make sure you are running only mutually exclusive tests eg don't run tests for user is present in database and delete user tests in parallel. This is because when one tests would be checking for users in DB another tests would have deleted that users already.**

**so make sure the tests are mutually exclusive  eg two different users trying to buy some items. This are mutually exclusive use case.**

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you don't need this answer now but i just solved this problem and i wanted to share it so that anyone face it in future have the solution.

You just need to throw null pointer exception like this

```html
 @After
    public void closeBrowser(){
        try{
        driver.quit();
        } catch(NullPointerException e){
            System.out.println("NullPointerException thrown!");
        }
    }
```